# Asp.net /sharepoint server 2010 integration

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

We have a asp.net application. Would like to integrate with sharepoint issue tracking application we are building.

We would like customer to login in asp.net application and when a link is clicked, it should pass login and other info (like customer id) and display a new issue list so that they can enter rest of information and submit.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They have to share the membership provider , using the FBA within SP2010.
Here is a Walkthrough http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/01/05/writing-a-custom-membership-provider-and-using-it-for-fba-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-from-the-scratch/
Then make a custom Form for the Issue reading the Session varialbles to fill in the Form.